# Multiple indexing in a table mysql

Tags: mysql, indexing

I have a table structure like this

```
`CREATE TABLE `like_user` (
 `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `sender_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `receiver_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `created` datetime NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
 KEY `index_user` (`sender_id`,`receiver_id`))`
```

I have indexed both `sender_id` and `receiver_id`. If I try to query this

```
`Select * from like_user where sender_id = 10`
```

The index works fine but on the other way around it doesn't.

```
`Select * from like_user where receiver_id = 11`
```

How can I make the index work on both the conditions.

The use case is that `sender_id` is the one who is liking a user and the person who sender id is liking is stored in `receiver_id`. So If sender wants to see all the users he likes, then indexing works, but if the receiver_id wants to see which senders have liked him, indexing stops working. how we can resolve it?

Comment: Do you have any queries other than these two which you expect to be running?

Comment: @Akina I do not understand? so it can be achieved? Otherwise the one query will be slower as user grows then the other one

Comment: Imagine a real life index at the back of a book.  The index is sorted by Sender then Receiver.  So, all of Sender 1's entries are in the same space, and sorted by the Receiver.  This makes it very easy to find the entries for any individual Sender, and also very easy to narrow that down to one Receiver *for that one Sender*.  But, if you want all the data for a single Receiver, it's scattered all over the index; some in Sender 1's space, some in Sender 2's space, and so on.  If you want to make it easy to find a given Receiver in the index, you need and index that start with Receiver.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only prefix can be used. Postfix cannot. I think that two separate indices, one by sender and another by receiver, will be reasonable:

```sql
CREATE TABLE `like_user` (
 `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `sender_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `receiver_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `created` datetime NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
 KEY (`sender_id`),
 KEY (`receiver_id`)
 );
```

One of these indices will be used for each table copy. For example, for

```
SELECT *
FROM like_user t1
JOIN like_user t2 ON t1.sender_id = t2.receiver_id;
```

the first table copy (t1) will use `` KEY (`sender_id`) `` whereas another table copy will use `` KEY (`receiver_id`) ``.

Comment: @MatBailie Sorry, linebreak was missed, so final `);` was not displayed.

Comment: Thank you very much. It worked. I didn't know it